# Creating email drafts in Outlook from Powershell level

Tags: powershell, outlook, office-automation

This question is more like a plea to get an explanation than help.

So, the goal is to create email draft in Outlook using PowerShell script.

On 3 systems, the following works as intended:

```
$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
```

But, on other systems, I get the following error:

```
Exception calling "CreateItem" with "1" argument(s): "Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' to interface
type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID
'{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A
(TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))."
At C:\Script.ps1:299 char:1
+ $Mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
```

---

After adding lines:

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
Add-Type -assembly "System.Runtime.Interopservices"
```

and changing $ol to:

```
$ol = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application')
```

it started to work.

Can you someone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook is a singleton which means on the system cannot be two instances run at the same time.

The [Marshal.GetActiveObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject?view=netframework-4.8) method allows obtaining a running instance of the specified object from the running object table (ROT). So, if Outlook is already run on the system you may retrieve it instead of trying to create a new instance. But even if you try to create a new one the system should detect such cases and connect to an already running instance of Outlook.

> Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A
> (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))."

Such errors can be resolved by adding a type library:

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. 
That's what we tried first. This line. But guy that tested it said it didn't work. Error was still there.
Only after we used full solution from my OP it worked.

Comment: The `GetActiveObject` is a meaningful change which leads to getting a running instance not relying on built-in mechanisms of getting an existing process when you try to create a new one.